# Trouble with SQL Statment

Tags: sql, if-statement

I have a database for a Train company. I want to combine two queries together so I can use them as one from a Java front end.

The first query returns the IDs of trains that are not full.

```
select TrainID 
  from Train 
 where Capacity > 0;
```

Each train has a capacity of 50 and I subtract one each time a seat is booked, so if the capacity is greater than zero, then there's a seat on board.

The second query returns the RouteID of a train given a destination and origin:

```
select * 
  from Timetable 
 where RouteID = (select RouteID 
                    from Routes 
                   where OriginID = "New York" 
                     and DestinationID = "LA");
```

### The Question/Need

I want to merge these two queries together so I can have something like:

```
Give me all the Timetable entries for this route ONLY IF there's room on the train.
```

I'm not a DB kinda guy so I'm just having trouble putting two and two together.

Edit: Schema is outlined below. Thanks for the answers so far, I'm going to try them now.

Routes

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RouteID       | varchar(25) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| OriginID      | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| DestinationID | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Duration      | int(3)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Stations

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| StationID | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Timetable

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| TimeID      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| RouteID     | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| TrainID     | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| DepartDate  | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| ArrivalDate | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Train

```
]+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TrainID  | varchar(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Capacity | int(11)     | NO   |     | 50      |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema for the Train and Timetable tables?

Comment: I think we need to know the schema of the two tables in question. I'm not sure which fields are in which tables...

Comment: How does the Train table relate to the Timetable and Route tables? Are there any foreign keys or link tables to implement many:many relationships? We need more schema information before we can help with this.

Comment: Edited the post to include the schema.

Comment: Just want to suggest that you go with a JOIN vs. a subquery. It will almost always outperform. Also, if you are keeping the ticket sales in the database then it's probably a bad idea to also track the capacity the way that you're doing it. Capacity should remain unchanged for a train (the train isn't getting smaller). Calculate the seats remaining in your queries. This is standard normalization (don't keep the same information twice in the DB - or information that can be calculated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a trainid in the timetable table this should be close

```
select a.*
from Timetable a
inner join Train b on a.trainid = b.trainid and b.capacity > 0
where a.RouteID =
     (
     select RouteID
     from Routes
     where OriginID = "New York" and DestinationID="LA"
     );
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but I can give you two possible reasons: (1) formatting, and (2) joining on a scalar value (should be in the `WHERE`).

Comment: thanks 
- can someone tell me why you think formatting means anything - if you are a programmer - dont we deal with crappy requirements and bad decisions everyday - why do we care waht it looks like if it get the job done! (no comment needed just a rant)

Comment: Another criticism would be that you used SELECT *. The OP stated he is not a DB guy so if he is going to learn, teach him correctly. But I did not mark this down. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from Timetable ti 
inner join Train tr 
    ON ti.TrainID = tr.ID 
    (Or whatever link there is between the two tables)
WHERE ti.RouteID in 
    (select RouteID from Routes where OriginID="New York" 
    and DestinationID="LA") 
AND tr.Capacity > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not stated how TrainID relates to Route or Timetable.. There needs to be a relationship of some sort to perform this task.

If it is a standard relationship then...

```
select t.* 
from Timetable t, Routes r, Trains tr
where r.OriginID ='New York' 
and r.DestinationID ="LA"
and t.RouteID = r.RouteID
and tr.RouteID = t.RouteID
amd tr.Capacity > 0;
```

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your schema slightly:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    Timetable t
        INNER JOIN
                Routes r
                ON t.RouteID = r.RouteID
        INNER JOIN
                Trains tr
                ON t.TrainID = tr.TrainID
WHERE   r.OriginID = 'New York'
AND     r.DestinationID = 'LA'
AND     tr.Capacity > 0
```

Joining to Routes rather than using a subquery could well perform better.

Comment: In this query where you have cared about Train Capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume that the TrainID is stored in the Routes table, this isnt clear in the question.

```
select * from Timetable where RouteID in 
(select RouteID from Routes 
 inner join Train on Train.TrainID = Routes.TrainID
where 
  OriginID = "New York" 
  and DestinationID = "LA"
  and Capacity > 0;
);
```